# Java integer array unknown size

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm looking for the "right" way to fix a problem with an array in Java:
i need an array for integers, without knowing the max value.

current solution for bypassing the limit on declaration:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

problem with this solution:

```
myArray.get(i);
```

wants to return a String instead of an int, and I need the int for further calculations...
Should i go with something else than an ArrayList or am i missing something else ?
(i'm guessing the last option...)

Comment: Why is it returning a String? It should return Integer. If you do int x = myArray.get(i) you will get the int that you need due to autoboxing/unboxing

Comment: I don't see any problem with ArrayList<Integer>

Comment: `ArrayList<>()` doesn't event compile. It should be `ArrayList<Integer>()`. Also, `get()` definitely doesn't return a `String`!

Comment: @verdesmarald ArayList<>() on the right hand side will work in Java 7 (one of those new features)

Comment: @gtgaxiola Ah, good to know. I'm still pretty sure `get()` will return an `Integer` though, even in Java 7!

Comment: @verdesmarald you are correct in the get() part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since you don't know how many items you want your array to hold, you should indeed use an `ArrayList`. Furthermore `myArray.get(i)` will indeed return an `int`, just try

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(3);
int a =  myArray.get(0);  // autoboxing
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: I retyped the code in question and now it does indeed compile without any problem. feeling kinda stupid if it was just a typo...

Comment: @Crimson Yea that's probably what it was. But remember: it happens to the best of us :-).

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayList is correct. It will not return a String, it will return the Integer. You can get an int from it automatically though because of the autoboxing.

```
 int x = myArray.get(i);
```

returns an Integer object and the contained int will be passed to your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this is wrong in **java6**

```
private ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

should be

```
private ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

you'd get an compiler error anyway so i assume its a typo. 
and your code would most definitely return Integer if you do

```
myArray.get(i);
```

Comment: NOT IN JAVA 7  you'll not get compiler errors

Comment: @gtgaxiola good to know. i dont really use Java 7.. thanks anyways